# Data problems in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to save data in roblox unfortunatly. It don't works can you help me?
Here's my code :

```
local ds = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Data")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local hidden = Instance.new("Model")
    hidden.Name = "hidden"
    hidden.Parent = player

    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Parent = leaderstats
    coins.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-coins") or 0
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-coins", coins.Value)
    coins.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-coins", coins.Value)
    end)

    local gems = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gems.Name = "Gems"
    gems.Parent = leaderstats
    gems.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-gems") or 0
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-gems", gems.Value)
    gems.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-gems", gems.Value)
    end)

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue")
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Parent = leaderstats
    level.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-level") or 1
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-level", level.Value)
    level.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-level", level.Value)
    end)

    local xp = Instance.new("IntValue")
    xp.Name = "XP"
    xp.Parent = hidden
    xp.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-xp") or 0
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-xp", xp.Value)
    xp.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-xp", xp.Value)
    end)

    local maxstamina = Instance.new("IntValue")
    maxstamina.Name = "MaxStamina"
    maxstamina.Parent = hidden
    maxstamina.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxstamina") or 100
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxstamina", maxstamina.Value)
    maxstamina.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxstamina", maxstamina.Value)
    end)

    local maxmagic = Instance.new("IntValue")
    maxmagic.Name = "MaxMagic"
    maxmagic.Parent = hidden
    maxmagic.Value = ds:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxmagic") or 100
    ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxmagic", maxmagic.Value)
    maxmagic.Changed:Connect(function()
        ds:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-maxmagic", maxmagic.Value)
    end)

    local stamina = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stamina.Name = "Stamina"
    stamina.Parent = hidden
    stamina.Value = maxstamina.value

    local magic = Instance.new("IntValue")
    magic.Name = "Magic"
    magic.Parent = hidden
    magic.Value = maxmagic.value

end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-coins", player.leaderstats.Coins.Value)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-gems", player.leaderstats.Gems.Value)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-xp", player.hidden.XP.Value)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-level", player.leaderstats.Level.Value)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-maxstamina", player.hidden.MaxStamina.Value)
    ds:setAsync(player.UserId.."-maxmagic", player.hidden.MaxMagic.Value)
end)
```

Thank's for helping me!
Also there's no error code it's just than when i test it my data don't save.
I have enabled the Studio Access to API Services.
Really i don't know what's happening i passed hours searching how to solve this but i didn't found it.

Comment: I guess roblox community shall be more helpful.

Comment: Have you published your game yet?

Comment: Yeah i've published it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your game hasn't been published yet, but nothing in your code looks like it would throw syntax errors, but it does look unsafe and wasteful.

Every call to `GetAsync()` and `SetAsync()` is a blocking network request that has a chance to fail and throw errors. Plus, there is a [limit on the number of requests](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Datastore-Errors) that you can send from the server, and if you hit that limit, your code will throw errors and will likely lose player data.

Rather than save one value per key, you can save a whole table of values into a single key. This greatly reduces the number of network requests and the chances that something could fail.

**Saving Data**

```
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local ds = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Data")

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local stats = player.leaderstats
    local hidden = player.hidden

    local data = {
        coins = stats.Coins.Value,
        gems = stats.Gems.Value,
        xp = hidden.XP.Value,
        level = stats.Level.Value,
        maxstamina = hidden.MaxStamina.Value,
        maxmagic = hidden.MaxMagic.Value,
    }

    -- wrap the request in a try-catch block to ensure that failures don't throw errors
    local success, result = pcall(function()
        -- save all the data as a JSON string
        ds:setAsync(player.UserId, HttpSevice:JSONEncode(data))
    end
    if not success then
        warn(string.format("Failed to save %s's data with error : %s", player.Name, tostring(result))
        -- TO DO: FIGURE OUT HOW YOU WANT TO HANDLE THIS ERROR.
        -- IF YOU DO NOTHING, THE PLAYER WILL LOSE THIS SESSION'S DATA
    end 
end)
```

**Loading Data**

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local defaultData = {
        coins = 0,
        gems = 0,
        xp = 0,
        level = 1,
        maxstamina = 100,
        maxmagic = 100,
    }
    local loadedData = defaultData
    local success, result = pcall(function()
         return ds:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end
    if success then
        if result then
            -- if we've successfully loaded the data, parse the stored json data
            print(string.format("An old player named %s has returned with data : %s!", player.Name, result))
            -- player data should look like this :
            -- {"coins":0,"xp":0,"gems":0,"level":1,"maxstamina":100,"maxmagic":100}
            local parseSuccess, parseResult = pcall(function()
                return HttpService:JSONDecode(result)
            end)
            if parseSuccess then
                loadedData = parseResult
            else
                warn(string.format("Failed to parse %s with error : %s", tostring(result), tostring(parseResult)) 
            end
        else
            -- we have a new player
            print(string.format("New player named %s has joined!", player.Name))
        end
    else
        warn(string.format("Something went wrong fetching %s's data : %s", player.Name, tostring(result))
        -- TO DO: FIGURE OUT HOW YOU WANT TO HANDLE THIS ERROR.
        -- IF YOU DO NOTHING, THE PLAYER'S DATA WILL BE THE DEFAULT DATA USED FOR
        -- NEW PLAYERS
    end

    -- create the leaderstats and hidden values, load the data from the loadedData table
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local hidden = Instance.new("Model")
    hidden.Name = "hidden"
    hidden.Parent = player

    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Parent = leaderstats
    coins.Value = loadedData.coins

    local gems = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gems.Name = "Gems"
    gems.Parent = leaderstats
    gems.Value = loadedData.gems

    local level = Instance.new("IntValue")
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Parent = leaderstats
    level.Value = loadedData.level

    local xp = Instance.new("IntValue")
    xp.Name = "XP"
    xp.Parent = hidden
    xp.Value = loadedData.xp

    local maxstamina = Instance.new("IntValue")
    maxstamina.Name = "MaxStamina"
    maxstamina.Parent = hidden
    maxstamina.Value = loadedData.maxstamina

    local maxmagic = Instance.new("IntValue")
    maxmagic.Name = "MaxMagic"
    maxmagic.Parent = hidden
    maxmagic.Value = loadedData.maxmagic

    local stamina = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stamina.Name = "Stamina"
    stamina.Parent = hidden
    stamina.Value = loadedData.maxstamina

    local magic = Instance.new("IntValue")
    magic.Name = "Magic"
    magic.Parent = hidden
    magic.Value = loadedData.maxmagic
end)
```

Comment: I've got an error : HTTP Service is not a valid member of DataModel. What should i do @Kylaaa?

Comment: now it's says unable to cast value of std::string. I searched it's says that my data had nt been encoded. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional logs and safety checks. Hopefully that should give a more clear message about what's happening.

Comment: Now it puts the same error message but in warning. What should I do?

Comment: what is the full text of the warning? The warning should show you what it is trying to parse into JSON. It could be that the string isn't valid JSON or there's some other issue.

Comment: The warning is : `Failed to parse table: 0x51db68f72777cea2 with error : Unable to cast value to std::string.` What should I do?

Comment: for some reason, you are getting a table back from this DataStore and not a string. if you iterate over all the keys and values of the table, does it have the values you would expect?

Comment: Yay it works! But now the data is not given to the stats. Like i dont know if the data don't save or don't load but the data is now given and there is no error code

Comment: It's like if the data don't save correctly or the data is not assingned correctly to the stats.